# How to define a React component to use an interchangeable context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have the following component:

```js
export const ActionCell = () => {
  const {
    edit,
    handleEditComplete,
    handleEditCancel,
    handleEdit,
    handleDelete,
  } = useRow();

  return (
    <StyledActionCell>
      <Group>
        {edit ? (
          <>
            <Complete onClick={handleEditComplete} />
            <Cancel onClick={handleEditCancel} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Edit onClick={handleEdit} />
            <Delete onClick={handleDelete} />
          </>
        )}
      </Group>
    </StyledActionCell>
  );
};
```

I want to reuse this component across my application, but with different contexts using the same API. So all functions and variables coming from the hook would be available but the implementation of the logic in the provider is different. How would I go about implementing this?

Currently the `useRow` references one of the 2 contexts, so it will error when using the context which is not referenced.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use different context without telling the `useContext` from where to take the data.

What you can do is to use same `Context` in different places.

```
const ActionContext = React.createContext()
...
return (<>
    <ActionContext.Provider value={...value1}><ActionCell /></ActionContext.Provider>
    <ActionContext.Provider value={...value2}><ActionCell /></ActionContext.Provider>
    <ActionContext.Provider value={...value3}><ActionCell /></ActionContext.Provider>
</>)
```

Same component, same context provider, different provided values

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it a bit more and could edit the component to inject the function:

```js
interface ActionCellProps {
  useRow: () => RowContextProps;
}

export const ActionCell = ({ useRow }: ActionCellProps) => {
  const {
    edit,
    handleEditComplete,
    handleEditCancel,
    handleEdit,
    handleDelete,
  } = useRow();

  return (
    <StyledActionCell>
      <Group>
        {edit ? (
          <>
            <Complete onClick={handleEditComplete} />
            <Cancel onClick={handleEditCancel} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Edit onClick={handleEdit} />
            <Delete onClick={handleDelete} />
          </>
        )}
      </Group>
    </StyledActionCell>
  );
};
```

If anyone has a better idea I would love to hear it though.

Comment: I've never seen a hook used as a prop before, I don't think that's valid. I would suggest making each variable a prop and using the hook in the parent component.

Comment: I used context here because this cell resides with other cells in a row, which all heavily depend on each other. Without context I would have to pass all variables and functions directly cluttering the code.

Comment: Also, to elaborate, the above does work. If you make both contexts use the same type `RowContextProps`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the useRow hook to obtain the values provided by different contexts? If so, I can provide an idea.

First create your context and hook:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const ContextA = createContext(null)

export const ContextB = createContext(null)

export const useRow = () => {
  const dataA = useContext(ContextA)
  const dataB = useContext(ContextB)
  return dataA || dataB
}
```

import `useRow` to use any where under the ContextA or ContextB.

```
const ActionCell = () => {
  const {
    edit,
    handleEditComplete,
    handleEditCancel,
    handleEdit,
    handleDelete,
  } = useRow();
  return (
    <StyledActionCell>
      <Group>
        {edit ? (
          <>
            <Complete onClick={handleEditComplete} />
            <Cancel onClick={handleEditCancel} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Edit onClick={handleEdit} />
            <Delete onClick={handleDelete} />
          </>
        )}
      </Group>
    </StyledActionCell>
  );
}
```

And do not pass a hook as component props. read about [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and [Calling a React hook conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827350/calling-a-react-hook-conditionally).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions all, in the end I opted for defining an interface for my context and having different files which implement this interface. As given below:

The interface in its own file:

```
interface RowContextProps {
...
}

export const RowContext = createContext<RowContextProps | undefined>(undefined);
```

The hook in the same directory but a different file:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { RowContext } from "./context";

export const useRow = () => {
  const context = useContext(RowContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useRow must be used within a RowProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

And in a different directory (close to the code using it) the implementation:

```
interface RowProviderProps {
...
}

export const RowProvider = ({ ... }: RowProviderProps) => {

  ...logic here

  return (
    <RowContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...all variables and functions from the interface here
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </RowContext.Provider>
  );
};
```